# Excel VBA code won't run on some computers

Tags: excel, vba

I have constructed a template for my department.
Within this template I use a code on 2 different sheets, to update the Pivottables.

The problem isn't with the code, but I'll insert it anyway.
The main problem is that the code **won't** work, for some of my colleagues.

We're a Danish company, whereas the coorporate languague is **English**, but for some reason, a couple of my colleagues has Danish as the main language on their computer/Excel. And it is also these colleagues, which experience a dysfunctional template.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String

Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Sales")

PivotName = "Salgsmoms1"
LastRow = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht2.Cells(LastRow, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address(False, False, xlA1)

NewRange = sht2.Name & "!" & "A1:" & LastColumn

sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)


sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"code won't work, for some of my colleagues"* is no useful error description because it doesn't explain anything. Wat error do you get and in which line? • If you don't get an error please be very specific of what happens instead of what you expect to happen or give a [mcve].

Comment: @Patrick-S: As [PEH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%e1%b4%87%ca%9c) says, please give us more information...we can't help with issues such as Internationalization **if we don't know where the error is happening**

Comment: @Patrick - *Welcome to [so]!* ... How do you know the problem isn't with the code?  (keep in mind that *"because it works on other computers"* is not a reason, since there are often considerations that need to be made for different operating systems, regional settings, user permissions, even file location, etc.  If you're indeed someone sure the problem is *not* the code, then it should not be included. (See the definition of *[mcve]*)  But regardless, as already stated, **nobody can help you if you don't explain what's wrong**.

Comment: @PatrickS: have you tried [stepping through the code with F8](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) on those users' workstations?

Comment: I bet this is an OS regional settings issue, and there are date format strings in the source data for the pivot table...

Answer (score 0):

To me the following line is the only one that looks problematic and might cause an issue

```
NewRange = sht2.Name & "!" & "A1:" & LastColumn
```

Fiddling the address together like this could possibly result in an invalid address. If you  use a `.Address(External:=True)` instead you can always to be sure that it is valid. Nevertheless I think `SourceData:=` wants a range object instead of an address.

Therefore I suggest …

1. Use `Option Explicit`.
2. Give the `SourceData:=NewRange` as range object instead of an address.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Sales")

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")

    Dim PivotName As String
    PivotName = "Salgsmoms1"

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = sht2.Cells(LastRow, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

    Dim NewRange As Range
    Set NewRange = sht2.Range("A1", LastCell)

    sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
    sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
End Sub
```

If this code shows the same error then I bet the error is not code dependent.

Comment: *not code dependent* - unless it's an internationalization issue, with date strings in the pivot table?